# Reinstall apache2

Tags: apache2, reinstall

It seems a simple `apt-get install apache2` does not completely install Apache2 as I can still see it on one of the processes when running `top`. How does one reinstall Apache2 on his Ubuntu Server?

This is the command:

```
root@unl01:~# which apache2

/usr/sbin/apache2
root@unl01:~# whereis apache2
apache2: /usr/sbin/apache2 /etc/apache2 /usr/lib/apache2 /usr/share/apache2 /usr/share/man/man8/apache2.8.gz
root@unl01:~# apt-get remove apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
```

After that when I install the Apache2 again the install fail:

```
root@unl01:~# apt-get install apache2

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubu                   ntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_Release - mkstemp (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

[Source](http://www.sillycodes.com/2015/06/quick-tip-couldnt-create-temporary-file.html)

Comment: I tried that on Terminal but the the service Apache2 still does not work